# With CSS, can I get the font shorthand and change the font size?

Tags: css

Blogger designer has a font option that outputs something like this: `font: normal normal 16px serif`.

Is there a way with pure CSS that I can get the font size declared in the shorthand and modify it like so: `font-size: calc(16px / 1.25)`.

I tried using `font-size: calc(inherit / 1.25)`, but that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: use 125% as value *A positive <percentage> value, relative to the parent element's font size.* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Comment: In testing, if i use font-size: 100%, the result is not equal to 16px;

Comment: share how you are testing this, we need to see the CSS applied to a HTML

Comment: I made a mistake, it is equal to 16px. Using percentages would work perfectly. If you make it as your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use percetange value like below:

```
font-size:calc(100%/1.25);
```

> A positive `<percentage>` value, relative **to the parent element's font size**. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)</sup>